Firebase Realtime data storage from ESP32
I'm tying to test the realtime connectivity with myesp32 using ardunio  IDE in googlefirebase ,but errors as mentioned bellow, can anyone tried and worked correctly , please help me ??

Code :
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>               //we are using the ESP32
//#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>      // uncomment this line if you are using esp8266 and comment the line above
#include <Firebase_ESP_Client.h>

//Provide the token generation process info.
#include "addons/TokenHelper.h"
//Provide the RTDB payload printing info and other helper functions.
#include "addons/RTDBHelper.h"

// Insert your network credentials
#define WIFI_SSID ""
#define WIFI_PASSWORD ""

// Insert Firebase project API Key
#define API_KEY ""

// Insert RTDB URLefine the RTDB URL */
#define DATABASE_URL "" 

//Define Firebase Data object
FirebaseData fbdo;

FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseConfig config;

unsigned long sendDataPrevMillis = 0;
int count = 0;
bool signupOK = false;                     //since we are doing an anonymous sign in 

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("Connecting to Wi-Fi");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(300);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected with IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();

  /* Assign the api key (required) */
  config.api_key = API_KEY;

  /* Assign the RTDB URL (required) */
  config.database_url = DATABASE_URL;

  /* Sign up */
  if (Firebase.signUp(&config, &auth, "", "")){
    Serial.println("ok");
    signupOK = true;
  }
  else{
    Serial.printf("%s\n", config.signer.signupError.message.c_str());
  }

  /* Assign the callback function for the long running token generation task */
  config.token_status_callback = tokenStatusCallback; //see addons/TokenHelper.h
  
  Firebase.begin(&config, &auth);
  Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);
}

void loop(){
  if (Firebase.ready() && signupOK && (millis() - sendDataPrevMillis > 15000 || sendDataPrevMillis == 0)){
    sendDataPrevMillis = millis();
    // Write an Int number on the database path test/int
    if (Firebase.RTDB.setInt(&fbdo, "test/int", count)){
      Serial.println("PASSED");
      Serial.println("PATH: " + fbdo.dataPath());
      Serial.println("TYPE: " + fbdo.dataType());
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("FAILED");
      Serial.println("REASON: " + fbdo.errorReason());
    }
    count++;
    
    // Write an Float number on the database path test/float
    if (Firebase.RTDB.setFloat(&fbdo, "test/float", 0.01 + random(0,10))){
      Serial.println("PASSED");
      Serial.println("PATH: " + fbdo.dataPath());
      Serial.println("TYPE: " + fbdo.dataType());
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("FAILED");
      Serial.println("REASON: " + fbdo.errorReason());
    }
  }
}

this is the code i used  and the code uploaded succesfully but getting theseerror in serial monitor,

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.
